# Recurrence Relation with generating function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

We have the generating function $$1/(1−2x−x^2)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$
Show $$a_n^2 + a_{n+1}^2 = a_{2n+2}$$.

I am thinking of finding a 2 × 2 matrix A and the text gives a hint of $$A^{n+2}= \left( \begin{smallmatrix} a_n&a_{n+1}\\ a_{n+1}&a_{n+2} \end{smallmatrix} \right)$$ and consider the top left entry of the matrix product $A^{n+2}A^{n+2}$. I do not exactly understand this hint.

Comment: The hint is saying you can find a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ such that,

$$A^2 = \begin{bmatrix}
a_0&a_1\\
a_1&a_2
\end{bmatrix},$$

and for any $n$,

$$A^{n+2} = \begin{bmatrix}
a_n&a_{n+1}\\
a_{n+1}&a_{n+2}
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then,

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_{2n+2} & a_{2n+3}\\
a_{2n+3}&a_{2n+4}
\end{bmatrix}=A^{2n+4}=A^{n+2}A^{n+2}=\begin{bmatrix}
a_n^2 + a_{n+1}^2&a_na_{n+1}+a_{n+1}a_{n+2}\\
a_na_{n+1}+a_{n+1}a_{n+2}&a_{n+1}^2+a_{n+2}^2
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Setting the top left entries equal yields the result. All that's left is to derive $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:This may help you to solve the problem:

$$\frac{1}{1-2x-x^2}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}.(\frac{1}{x+1-\sqrt2}-\frac{1}{x+1+\sqrt 2}$$

Now expand $\frac{1}{1+(x-\sqrt2)}$ and $\frac{1}{1+(x+\sqrt2)}$ and sum up terms with identical powers, you get the expansion of $\frac{1}{1-2x-x^2}$. Now you can check $a^2_n+a^2_{n+1}= a_{2n+2}$.

Comment: i would use the terms that i sum up and check with the matrix?